# Need to get the difference between two time in seconds

Tags: bash, ksh, date, aix

The following two variables contain the start time and the end time , need to 
get the difference between these two time in seconds

```
start_time=06:07:25
end_time=07:02:08
```

Desired Output

```
diff_time= 3283 Seconds
```

I use AIX 6.1 machine with ksh88.

Comment: Is it possible to get your timestamps in a different format? This becomes much easier if you, e.g., use `date +%s` to get your start and end times... Further, assuming localtime, what you want to do isn't actually possible in general with the format you have (consider what happens if you cross a daylight saving time boundary).

Comment: Does AIX `date` have the `-d` switch? I think it doesn't but I'm not sure.

Comment: @terdon No, only GNU and BusyBox do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using bash:

```
t2s()
{
  local T=$1;shift
  echo $((10#${T:0:2} * 3600 + 10#${T:3:2} * 60 + 10#${T:6:2})) 
}

start_time=06:07:25
end_time=07:02:08

diff_time=$(( $(t2s $end_time) - $(t2s $start_time) ))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're sure that `end_time` is always greater than `start_time`, you can use Perl like so:

```
export start_time=06:07:25
export end_time=07:02:08
perl -e '
    ($h1,$m1,$s1) = split /:/,$ENV{start_time};
    ($h2,$m2,$s2) = split /:/,$ENV{end_time};
    $delta_h = $h2 - $h1;
    $delta_m = $m2 - $m1;
    if( $delta_m < 0 ) { $delta_m = $delta_h-- * 60 + $m2 - $m1; }
    $delta_s = $s2 - $s1;
    if( $delta_s < 0 ) { $delta_s = $delta_m-- * 60 + $s2 - $s1; }
    print "diff_time=", $delta_h * 3600 + $delta_m * 60 + $delta_s, " seconds\n"
'
```

Note that you can do this purely in `{k,}sh` with parameter expansion and shell arithmetic. I'm just using Perl for convenience.

Here it is in POSIX shell script:

```
start_time=06:07:25
end_time=07:02:08
h1=${start_time%%:*}
start_time=${start_time#*:}
m1=${start_time%%:*}
s1=${start_time#*:}
h2=${end_time%%:*}
end=${end#*:}
m2=${end_time%%:*}
s2=${end_time#*:}
delta_h=$(( h2 - h1 ))
delta_m=$(( m2 - m1 ))
if [ $delta_h -lt 0 ];then
    delta_m=$(( delta_h * 60 + m2 -m1 ))
    delta_h=$(( delta_h - 1 ))
fi
delta_s=$(( s2 - s1 ))
if [ $delta_s -lt 0 ];then
    delta_s=$(( delta_m * 60 + s2 - s1 ))
    delta_m=$(( delta_m - 1 ))
fi
delta_all=$(( delta_h * 3600 + delta_m * 60 + delta_s ))
printf "diff_time = %d seconds\n" $delta_all
```